# Doing $wpdb->get_results returns NULL, doing the same query in my DB returns correct value

Tags: wp-query, query, wpdb

I have this query to do in my code:

```
  function get_item($id){
    global $wpdb;

    $post_id_query = "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = ". $id ." AND meta_key LIKE '%main%'";
    $call_post_id_call = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($post_id_query));

    return $call_post_id_call;
  }

  $main_item = get_item(34487);
```

If I run `SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = 34487 AND meta_key LIKE '%main%'` on my DB it works...

I'm not very keen on wordpress to be honest.

Comment: Try to run print $wpdb->last_query; before the return call and check the exact query being executed. Also, couldn't see any issues in the script, it should work if the query works in you DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script will help you to identify if there any error exists in the query.

```
$wpdb -> show_errors ();
$call_post_id_call = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($post_id_query));
$wpdb -> print_error ();
```